# error when trying ''npm install node-sass --save dev"

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cmd

PLEASE HELP!
Just a noob here, I am trying to work with some npm packages like sass, and I get this strange error mentioning LINUX OS, which was just tried to install on my computer.
How to fix this? Just to continue with my work, please.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

Parameter `--save-dev` instead of `--save dev` ，You can run `npm --help` to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to node-sass package docs there are prerequisites for windows:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

[image: NPM node-sass install]

**You can find the node-gyp install details here:**
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install sass while your server is still running and getting this error, you can try restarting your server.

Comment: Welcome to SO! it seems that the OP problem was caused by a lack of a dash/hyphen in --save-dev (--save dev). But anyway, _try restarting your server_ and installing after restart, or shutdown and installing while offline? Try to be more explicit and give appropriate steps; it will increase the odds that you will be upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
npm install -g node-sass

Comment: Answering with "try this" without any explanation or reference links is not very helpful to the original poster or to future readers. Also an error with a software dependency due to unsupported OS is not likely to be fixed by installing the node module globally.